# Executing Same Jenkins job by picking fail_skip xml once first execution is over

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, testng

I am from QA automation and pretty new to jenkins, below is my case

Process: I have a jenkins job which picks up a file criticalsuite.xml (testng) and triggers the execution. once the job completes, it generates a file name fail_skip xml in the same workspace.

Question: How do I configure a job to pick up this fail_skip.xml and trigger the execution automatically once the main job completes execution.

CUrrently, we are manually triggering the same job by pasting the fail_skip xml. I basically want to get rid of this maual intervention

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Jenkins pipeline, It would be easy to do it in a different stage. In my below declarative Jenkinsfile example, the stage-01 create a file and stage-02 parse it and read it.

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('01') {
            steps {
                writeFile file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/details.yml", text: """
                    name: Scott
                    address:
                        houseNumber: x01
                        city: XX
                        country: Space
                """ 
            }
        }
        stage('02') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def yamlContent = readYaml file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/details.yml"
                    println yamlContent.address.country
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can even extend this scenario with
post-build stage. meaning after the job run depends on SUCCESS or FAILURE you can decide what to do. Please take a look at this [jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) for more details. something like this:

```
pipeline {
   agent any;
   stages {
     ...
   }
   post {
        success {
            script {
                def yamlContent = readYaml file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/details.yml"
                println yamlContent.address.city
            }
        }
        failure {
            echo "IT'S FAIL"
        }
    }
}
```